# What is the difference between a `String x = expr` and `var x = expr as String`?

Tags: flutter, dart, types

While developing a Flutter app, I ran into a problem where out of two seemingly similar things, only one really works. The other gives an error.

```dart
// this does NOT work
// gives error: E/flutter (13080): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 
// type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Route<String>?' in type cast

onButtonPress() async {
  String ret = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page");
  print(ret);
}
```

```dart
// this works !
onButtonPress() async {
  var ret = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page") as String;
  print(ret);
}
```

Both looks like doing the same thing - casting the value returned from the route into a String. But why does only one of them works ?

Comment: Can you post your `analysis_options.yaml`? It's possible you have implicit dynamic disabled. This is a setting that tries to warn you when there's a "hidden" cast (as is the case in your first example)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a variable as String X , that means you tell the program specifically that - I am sure that the value I am going to get will be String and I want it to be stored in X . If the value returned is not String type it will throw an error.

When you assign the variable as var X , that means you are telling the program that I am not sure what will be the type of value which will be returned but I want the returned value to be returned as 'String ' (so even if you get any response as int or double or anything else it will try to use the complete value returned as string) . So var helps in getting rid of type errors when you are not sure of the type  , but it's always best practice to know what type you are getting and define accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As your error states:

```
  // gives error: E/flutter (13080): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 
  // type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Route<String>?' in type cast
  onButtonPress() async {
  String ret = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page");
  print(ret);
}
```

You are trying to assign a MaterialPageRoute<dynamic!> to a Route<String!>.

This is a simple case of type mismatching.

In the other example that you have posted, you are using var instead of String. This allows you to assign every type that you want to it.

Comment: But what's troubling me is the fact that `ret` is infact a `String`. I know this because of what gets printed out in the logs `print(ret)`. 

So why the error message is talking about `MaterialPageRoute` or `Route` ?

Answer (score 0):

`await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page")` returns a future, which is not a string.
the scope of a `var` is just a generic variable that can be anything upon assignation.

Comment: Isn't this misleading ? when you use `await` in front of a `Future<T>` , you indeed get the T as your return from it and not a Future<T>.

Comment: no, you will get the value if you use await. If not, you'll get a future.

Comment: > await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page") returns a future, which is not a string. 


I believe this statement is wrong. Because that expression indeed evaluates to a `String` value (and NOT a `Future`).

Comment: @krumpli That's what I said. You will get the value and not a Future. But your answer says that you will get a Future. Hence the misleading.